# Drawing shape from an array in Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written this code:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
  #map, html, body
  {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=drawing,geometry"></script>

<script>
var coordinates = [];
var all_shapes = [];

var selectedShape;
</script>

<script>
draw_shape()
{
    all_shapes[0];
}
</script>

<script>
function clearSelection()
{
    if(selectedShape)
    {
        selectedShape.setEditable(false);
        selectedShape = null;
    }
}

function setSelection(shape)
{
    clearSelection();
    selectedShape = shape;
    shape.setEditable(true);
}

function deleteSelectedShape()
{
    if (selectedShape)
    {
        selectedShape.setMap(null);
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function save_coordinates_to_array(newShapeArg)
{
    if(newShapeArg.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON)
    {
        var polygonBounds = newShapeArg.getPath();

        for(var i = 0 ; i < polygonBounds.length ; i++)
        {
            coordinates.push(polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //alert("Not polygon");/////////////
    }   
}
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 12, center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.344, 51.048)});

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.type;

        all_shapes.push(newShape);

        setSelection(newShape);

        save_coordinates_to_array(newShape);

        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {setSelection(newShape)});
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {clearSelection();});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input name="name" id="name" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Color</td>
    <td>
      <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#FF0000">&nbsp;</td>
          <td bgcolor="#00FF00">&nbsp;</td>
          <td bgcolor="#0000FF">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input name="save" type="button" value="Save" onClick="draw_shape()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input name="delete" type="button" value="Delete" onClick="deleteSelectedShape()"></td>
  </tr>  
</table>

<div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

It's using Google maps library to draw shapes.
This is the array `var` `all_shapes = [];` that saves all new shapes have been created.
And this is the function that has to draw shapes from the array:

```
<script>
draw_shape()
{
    all_shapes[0];
}
</script>
```

I have a question. How can I draw shapes again from this array.

Comment: And of course I'm a starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your draw_shape method. If you click on Save button, all objects on the map will be removed and after 2 seconds they will be restored from the array.

```
   function draw_shape()
   {
      for(var i=0;i<all_shapes.length;i++) all_shapes[i].setMap(null);

      setTimeout(function(){
        for(var i=0;i<all_shapes.length;i++) all_shapes[i].setMap(map);
      }, 2000);
    }
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sasha_thor/H7EAD/35/).

Comment: Thanks Thor. This is the answer though but there is one more problem. I'm going to save all shapes in the database and this is the reason that I used this method. So I think your method just hide shapes and doesn't let us to save the shape in the database. What is your opinion to save shapes in the database?